# Creating portable CDT library in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, build, eclipse-cdt

I have some specific libraries used for building embedded code. But every time I create a a cdt project in eclipse, I have to add this libraries to the project. I know one can create a library project and then create a dependency to this from the main application. But what I ant quite figure out here is the toolchain setting propagation.

When I create a project in eclipse, I am forced to define the toolchain to use for building. What I want is not to define a toolchain for the library project, but let eclipse use the defined toolchain for the main project referencing the library to build the library.

Sometimes, a library is built for AVR, sometimes for ARM, sometimes for PC. Each of this requires a different compiler. But once I specify a compiler for the library, this compiler is always being used to build even if that is not the required one at the time the library is been compiled.

I hope my question is clear? Thanks for your anticipated help.